# Android SQLite query with WHERE Strings passed by Intent not working

Tags: android, database, android-intent, android-sqlite, android-cursor

I am developing a simple recipe holder app for Android. I am new to Android programming. I have two activities - in the first one you check and input search variables, and the second one which is a ListView. The recipes can be searched by the values of their names, difficulty and dish type, by using this method:

```
public class DatabaseManager
{
 // other class stuff
 public Cursor getMatchingRecipes(String name, String difficulty, String recipeType)
 {
  // this method has been tested and works fine, the query itself works fine
 }
}
```

I am creating an intent to start the ListView activity like this:

```
//code from the SearchParametersActivity
Intent intent = new Intent(this, RecipesListActivity.class);
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("name", name); // name is a String variable with value from an EditText
bundle.putString("difficulty", difficulty.toString()); // from a Spinner
bundle.putString("type", type.toString()); // from a Spinner
bundle.putInt("action", DatabaseManager.GET_SEARCH);
intent.putExtras(bundle);
startActivity(intent);

cursor = dbManager.getMatchingRecipes(name, difficulty, type); // calling this from this activity works fine and gives me the correct entries from the database
```

And calling the query from the second activity like this:

```
//code from the RecipesListActivity
dbManager.open();
String name = getIntent().getExtras().getString("name");
String difficulty = getIntent().getExtras().getString("difficulty");
String type = getIntent().getExtras().getString("type");
cursor = dbManager.getMatchingRecipes(name, difficulty, type); // NOT WORKING
```

This query always gives ma an empty cursor.
I have already checked that the strings are passed correctly - they are all printed out the same way in both activities. However, if I input the **same exact** String values manually, I get the correct result.

```
String name1 = "egg";
String difficulty1 = "EASY";
String type1 = "MAIN_COURSE";

cursor = dbManager.getMatchingRecipes(name1, difficulty1, type1); // WORKS
```

A similar method which returns all of the database rows works fine in both activities, so I must be making some mistake with passing the values through the intent. This leaves me clueless, any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this way**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, RecipesListActivity.class);
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putExtra("name", name); // name is a String variable with value from an EditText
bundle.putExtra("difficulty", difficulty.toString()); // from a Spinner
bundle.putExtra("type", type.toString()); // from a Spinner
bundle.putExtra("action", DatabaseManager.GET_SEARCH);

startActivity(intent);
```

**//code from the RecipesListActivity**

```
dbManager.open();
String name = getIntent().getStringExtra("name");
String difficulty = getIntent().getStringExtra("difficulty");
String type = getIntent().getStringExtra("type");
```

Comment: I have tried calling dbManager.open() (and dbManager.close()) in various places, thinking that it may be a problem with many database connections active at once, but it did not give any effect. Thanks for your answer tho!